# JS is not worked for cocoon add and delete link for complex form in rails 7?

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am using ruby 3.1.0 and rails 7.0.3 and following this [followed this instruction for setup](https://www.bacancytechnology.com/blog/cocoon-gem-example-in-rails-6/)

create a user and friend model and add a relation between them

app/models/user.rb

```
has_many :friends, dependent: :destroy
accepts_nested_attributes_for :friends
```

app/models/friend.rb

```
belongs_to :user
```

app/controllers/users_controller.rb

```
  def new
    @user = User.new
    @friends = @user.friends.build
  end
  
  def create
    @user = User.new(user_params)
    if @user.save
      redirect_to user_path(@user)
    else
      render action: :new
    end
  end
  
  def show
    @user = User.find(params[:id])
    @friends = @user.friends
  end
  
  private
  
  def user_params
    params.require(:user).permit(:name, friends_attributes: [:id, :friend_name, :_destroy])
  end
```

app/views/new.html.erb

```
<%= form_for(@user) do |f| %>
   <div>
<div>
  <%= f.label :name %>
  <%= f.text_field :name %>
</div>

<div>
  <%= f.fields_for :friends do |t| %>
    <%= render "friend_fields", :f => t %>
  <% end %>
  
  <div>
    <br>
    <%= link_to_add_association "Add Friend", f, :friends %>
  </div>
</div>

<div>
  <br>
  <%= f.submit %>
</div>
```

app/views/_friend_fileds_html.erb

```
<div class="nested-fields">
  <%= f.label "Friend's name" %>
  <%= f.text_field :friend_name %>

  <%= link_to_remove_association "Delete", f %>
</div>
```

app/javascript/packs/application.js

```
 require('jquery')
 import "cocoon";
```

app/config/webpack/environment.js

```
const { environment } = require('@rails/webpacker')

const webpack = require('webpack')
environment.plugins.prepend('Provide',
new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
   $: 'jquery/src/jquery',
   jQuery: 'jquery/src/jquery'
})
)

 module.exports = environment
```

this is all about which I have made changes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recently implemented the cocoon gem in rails 7. You just need to do a little bit of setup.

First, add the jquery gem and cocoon gem.

```
gem 'jquery-rails'
gem 'cocoon'
```

add jquery.js to  **assets.rb**  file for precompiling.

```
Rails.application.config.assets.precompile += %w( jquery.js )
```

Don't forget to run  `rails assets:precompile`

Now, include jquery in  **application.html.erb**

```
<%= javascript_include_tag "jquery" %>
```

*When the main page is loaded, this line includes jQuery first in our application.

**This entire setup is for jQuery.**

**For the cocoon gem,**
Instead of importing cocoon, you need to import "@nathanvda/cocoon" in  **application.js** . Here is the syntax for that.

```
import "@nathanvda/cocoon"
```

Finally, Add cocoon to importmap (a new feature in Rails 7) by using,

```
bin/importmap pin @nathanvda/cocoon
```

*It will be Pinning "@nathanvda/cocoon"

No need to setup environment.js

**You can take reference from my GitHub repository, where I implemented the cocoon gem for the dynamic address field. :**   https://github.com/rutikkpatel/Cocoon-Gem